# Why does the page callback have two arguments?

Tags: 7, routes

```
function menufun_menu() {
  $items['menufun/%/bar/baz'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hi',
    'page callback' => 'menufun_hello',
    'page arguments' => array(1), // The matched wildcard.
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
* Page callback.
*/
function menufun_hello($a = NULL, $b = NULL) {
  return t('Hello. $a is @a and $b is @b', array('@a' => $a, '@b' => $b));
}
```

In the `menufun_menu()` function, the page argument for the `menufun_hello` callback is only one. Why does `menufun_hello()` have two parameters?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Menu callbacks are passed first the arguments defined in `page arguments` then excess arguments from the url.

So in the above example:

```
menufun/1/bar/baz
```

Will provide these vars:

```
$a = 1;
$b = NULL;
```

If you however provide an extra argument in the url:

```
menufun/1/bar/baz/2
```

You will transfer it to the menu callback:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
```

The other advantedge is like tim writes, that it allows reuse of the same code for various cases, making the module more maintainable.

Comment: in this url menufun/1/bar/baz/2, why it transfer 2 to the $b?

Comment: @enjoylife because it's the first non required argument. If baz was left out, the url wouldn't match, so it's not included, unless included under 'page arguments'

Comment: You can have an unlimited number of arguments after the required ones - eg menufun/1/bar/baz/2/arg3/arg4 will pass 4 arguments to your page callback - 1, 2, arg3, and arg4.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `menufun_hello()` takes up to two arguments, but as little as zero, since it provides defaults. This means that `menufun_menu()` could later pass another argument, and the function signature wouldn't have to change.

Comment: The function will always be called with at least one argument, because that is required in the menu definition. So the = NULL part is unecessary (unless that function is re-used in another menu definition for example)